# Does opening a checking account cause a hard credit pull?

Tags: united-states, credit-history, checking-account

I was going to open a new bank account, particularly the Wells Fargo promotion that puts $400 in your account if you meet some direct deposit requirements.

I called and asked if they will do a "hard" pull on my credit but they could not tell me.

In general does opening a checking account cause a credit report pull.

More importantly I guess, is are they required to ask my permission to make the pull considering I will have to give them all the information any ways just to open the account?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the bank, I would say most banks generally do not, and a few always do.

Schwab bank for example does a hard pull for all checking account openings. (at least for the first account with that customer, they often waive this if you are opening several accounts and already have one.)

If I recall Wells Fargo does not, at least they did not when I opened an account with them a few years ago (I did not have a social security number at the time however so I do not know if they would have if i did). To be sure you could ask at a branch as their phone and online support are very poor.

Generally either they will ask you during account opening, or it will be mentioned in the account's terms and conditions if they can run a credit check as part of the application. So if you read those it should tell you.

Comment: Does the law require that they atleast ask permission?

Comment: @JamieSiminoff They have to inform you if they will, however this can be buried in the enormous T&Cs document they hand you before opening the account and need not be obvious or prominent.

Comment: @JamieSiminoff By the way, I am assuming this is a US checking account. But it would help if you add a country tag as this kind of thing is place specific due to the legal nature.

Comment: Im curious why this answer is getting downvoted? Im fine to improve it if anyone has suggestions

Answer (score 1):

No.  In the US checking accounts are not included in a credit report.  Sometimes there will be a credit pull for an overdraft protection line of credit, just decline the overdraft protection.

Comment: I was just referring to the original opening of the account.  Is a hard pull done in this case?

Comment: Why would there be?  A checking account has nothing to do with credit.

Comment: Just applying for a job, they will ask to run your credit.  Credit reports are pulled for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly 30 years ago my mother added me to her checking account--which caused a hard pull noticed by the bank we were getting a mortgage from.  Neither of us had any idea that was going to happen.  This was an existing account of long standing but they checked me anyway.

Note that this was before they had to get permission to do a credit pull.

Answer (score -1):

I opened a checking and savings account at IQ Credit Union in the Pacific Northwest.

Even though I did not apply for credit, IQ Credit Union did a hard pull.  The hard pull hurt my excellent credit score.  The cost of my car and auto insurance went up - I confirmed this with the insurance company.

WATCH OUT!